# Get the variable from a query which is written on .xml c#

Tags: c#, sql, xml

I know my question is complicated but let me tell with codes. I have a query written on a .xml file. I need to get [Language] variable from it. I use c# as language. Here's my sql query on xml file :

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Code]
     ,[Language]
     ,[Multilanguage_Desc]
     ,[Abbrv]
     ,[Resource_ID]
     ,[Culture_String]
     ,[Is_Active]
     FROM [enVision-Development].[dbo].[Lookup_DOC_Document_Language]
```

How can I link it with my c# project. Thank you !!

Edit : Hi, let me tell you in this way :

```
<criteria_default_query>
 SELECT TOP 1000 [Code]
 ,[Language]
 ,[Multilanguage_Desc]
 ,[Abbrv]
 ,[Resource_ID]
 ,[Culture_String]
 ,[Is_Active]
 FROM [Development].[dbo].[Lookup_DOC_Document_Language]
```

I get the query code from the xml in a tag. (criteria default query) and in a c# page I get the inside of the tag by doing this : '

```
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("/root/chart/ListFeatures"))
        {
            xmlquery = node["criteria_query"].InnerText;
         }
```

Now I have the query as a string, is there a way that I can get the [language] variable from the query?

Comment: This doesn't seem complicated... just a little unsure as to what you are trying to do? Are you trying to extract a SQL statement from an XML file? Can you show the XML content if so?  Also what does "Link it with my c# project" mean exactly?

Comment: Syntax presented is Microsoft Sql server T-SQL. Can you be more specific regarding your problem? I do not see any trace of XML.

Comment: @Wheels73     I updated my question I hope you can understand me now :)

Comment: @UgurCan - So you now want to execute that SQL statement against your database and get the results back? If so, just execute the SQL statement with a SQL command type of Text.

Comment: @Wheels73 actually I want to get a variable from the user like ' Request.QueryString["lang"] ' from the 'http://localhost:55311/Default.aspx?lang=7 '. If user says 7, I need to put the 7th language to the query

Comment: @UgurCan - OK...the same still applies, but when you have your language id... just append this to the SQL statement. i.e. "Where [Language] = " + ID   and execute it.

Comment: Run the SQL Query as a stored Procedure from c#.  The query will return the selected items to c#.

Comment: @Wheels73 Thank you for your answers, I did it with Request.Querystring function !! :)